# Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql

I have built a search form, that get the country of an item:

```
$location = !empty($country) ? ' AND location='.System::escape($country) : '';

$getproduct = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE title LIKE ? ".$international." ".$auction." AND NOW() < enddate ".$location." ".$condition." ".$category."");
```

I am using a get form with an array full of countries, so the country is like:

```
<option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="United States">United States</option>
```

But I am getting a syntax error:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'Kingdom' at line 1 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\auction\application\model\ProductModel.php on line 335

Comment: Use `'".$var."'` for strings.

Comment: I tried that but then no results are being showns. I have stored the values in the database as: United Kingdom

Do I have to store them like United+Kingdom and then str_replace the + with a space?

Comment: This `$location = !empty($country) ? ' AND location='.System::escape($country) : '';` looks like it's part of the problem. How to fix; I've no idea. But the quoting is important.

Comment: NVM. Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. You know you can post your own answer to show people what you did to fix it. The choice is yours, *cheers*

Comment: You either should provide an answer as to how it was resolved, or delete the question. As it stands, your question will remain as being unanswered/unresolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Fred.

I did the following:

**Before:**

```
$location = !empty($country) ? ' AND location='.System::escape($country) : '';
```

**After**

```
$location = !empty($country) ? " AND location='".System::escape($country)."'" : '';
```

As Fred mention string need to be encased with apostrophes.